# Maximum-Likelihood Estimator: What problems occur if data is not i.i.d.?

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, parameter-estimation

This is a question from an exam:

> You want to estimate the parameters for a gaussian distribution using
>   the Maximum-Likelihood Method for an i.i.d. set of data. What role
>   does the property i.i.d. play? What difficulties occur if your List of
>   data is not i.i.d?

I basically know how ML works but I have troubles getting behind the reason why data which is *not* i.i.d. would cause troubles. Could anyone explain this to me? Please note that as a computer scientist I am not a mathematician - please keep it simple for me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the likelihood function of the data $L(\text{Data} \mid \theta)$. The data in this case are comprised of $n$ iid random draws from a normal distribution $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$. So
$$
L(\text{Data} \mid \theta) = L(x_1, \dots, x_n \mid \theta).
$$
But we know that two independent events $A, B$ can have their joint probability $P(A,B)$ decomposed to $P(A)P(B)$ by the definition of independence. Thus,
$$
L(x_1, \dots, x_n \mid \theta) = L(x_1 \mid \theta) \cdots L(x_n \mid \theta) = \mathcal{N}(x_1 \mid \theta) \cdots \mathcal{N}(x_n \mid \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathcal{N}(x_i \mid \theta).
$$
Now recall that the MLE for this scenario is computed by setting
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \prod_{i=1}^n \mathcal{N}(x_i \mid \theta) = 0.
$$
Independence allows us to exploit the exponential form of the normal PDF: the product of all of these PDFs creates a sum in the exponent, which makes solving the optimization problem a breeze analytically (though not necessarily algebraically!).

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for answering. No I didn't found it out yet but if I got you right the data not being i.i.d. would not allow us to write: $ L(x_1, \dots, x_n \mid \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathcal{N}(x_i \mid \theta) $ because their joint distribution looks (or at least might look) different, right?

Comment: Right, it's hard to say what the join distribution would look like since that would depend wildly on the dependency structure. A relatively simple example to look at to see how we can't decompose the likelihood function in the same manner if it's not iid would be a first order Markov chain.

Comment: Alright, I got it. Thank you :)